# git rebase results in error: fatal: Needed a single revision invalid upstream

Tags: git

I've been reading into git rebase recently and wanted to test it out myself but I'm encountering an error and so now I'm questioning my understanding. If you can help me correct my understanding that will be great. First off the error I'm getting is:

```
fatal: Needed a single revision
invalid upstream 'ABC-test1'
```

The images below is my understanding of rebase
[image]

[image]

Locally I have a branch `ABC-test1`. I created a branch off of `ABC-test1` and called it `ABC-test2` with `git checkout -b ABC-test2 ABC-test1`.

I then created a file `rebase1.py` with some content from `ABC-test1`. I then also created a file called `rebase1.py` with some content in branch `ABC-test2`, not the same as the content added to `rebase1.py`. My understanding is that, in this case, I consider `ABC-test1` the `master` branch in image1 and `ABC-test2` the `topic` branch in image1.

When I run `git rebase ABC-test1 ABC-test2` I am expecting to see the equivalent of image 2 such that my `ABC-test2` should contain everything from `ABC-test1`.  ie, `rebase1.py` in `ABC-test2` should contain everything form `ABC-test1` and `ABC-test2`.

What is wrong with my understanding?

Comment: Your description all sounds correct. The error message hints at something else though: git _didn't know what "abc-test1" meant_. Make sure you have the branch names right: look at `git branch` and try `git log ABC-test1` and `git log ABC-test2`.

Comment: To check, I ran through the commands you describe, and it worked exactly how you expected: https://gist.github.com/IMSoP/370dcd4d9f73c09533bd35a8a47e1e60 Presumably you made a mistake somewhere, but without the exact commands you ran, it's hard to say what.

Comment: Thanks, I just checked the history of my commands and I had a typo...thanks for the help.